# While loop only creates one dropdown box per client (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, while-loop

I am attempting to use two queries to set up multiple dropdown menus per doctor.  So far this is working, however it unfortunately pulls only the item.

I would like to have all of the 'expertises' available within the dropdown (and the expertise IDs as the option values).

I have set up the below while loop, however I have been unsuccessful in producing a dropdown for each Client_ID.

The first query (below) pulls the client ID from the area

```
$client_id = $_GET['doc_id'];
$physician_id_expertise = $client_id;

$doctor_query = 'SELECT * ';
$doctor_query.= 'FROM `primarycare_expertise` ';
$doctor_query.= 'WHERE `physician_id`=' . $client_id . ' ';
$doctor_result = mysql_unbuffered_query( $doctor_query );
```

The while loop incorporates the second query, which sets up the dropdown (pulling in all of the 'expertise' values).

```
while ($doctor_row = mysql_fetch_array( $doctor_result ))
{
    echo "<select name='doc_id_expertise_" . $doctor_row['pe_id'] . "' id='doc_id_expertise_" . $doctor_row['pe_id'] . "'>";

    $expert_query = 'SELECT * FROM `expertise` ';
    $expert_result = mysql_unbuffered_query( $expert_query );

    while ($expert_row = mysql_fetch_array( $expert_result )){
        if($doctor_row['expertise_id'] == $expert_row['expertise_id'])
        {
            $selected = "selected";
        } else {
            $selected = "";
        }
        echo "<option $selected value=" . $expert_row['expertise_id'] . ">" . $expert_row['expertise'] . "</option>";
    }

    echo "</select>";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

If any of you could help me out, I would be very appreciative!  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending new query while iterating through unbuffered result of previous query.  This does not work.  Try using `mysql_query` instead of `mysql_unbuffered_query` for the first query like this:

```
$doctor_result = mysql_query (
    "SELECT * FROM primarycare_expertise WHERE physician_id='$client_id'");
```

For subsequent queries you could still use `mysql_unbuffered_query` because they do not overlap.

See the following [page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php) for details.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly.  I've been using 'unbuffered' for most of my queries, forgot to change it for this one.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql package is deprecated BTW. Consider adopting to the mysqli extension instead.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php